# Respectively usage

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct if I want to say a unisex ambulant W.C. is provided on the ground level and a wheelchair-accessible unisex W.C.?

> A unisex ambulant W.C. and a wheelchair-accessible unisex W.C. ***are*** provided on the ground and roof levels respectively.

or

> A unisex ambulant W.C. and a wheelchair-accessible unisex W.C. ***is*** provided on the ground and roof levels respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Are** is correct.

Based on the explanation in rule 4 on [this page](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) which states:

> As a general rule, use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by *and*.
>
> Example:
>
> - A car and a bike **are** my means of transportation.
>
> But note these exceptions:
>
> Exceptions:
>
> - Breaking and entering is against the law.
> - The bed and breakfast was charming.
>
> In those sentences, *breaking and entering* and *bed and breakfast* are compound nouns.

Also, I found a very similar example [here](https://www.advancedenglishediting.com/blog/respectively-how-to-use-it-in-your-writing) which is:

> "The dog and the cat **were** named Jack and Sam, respectively."

Please note that the word "respectively" should be used with a comma, so the correct form of your sentence would be:

> A unisex ambulant W.C. and a wheelchair-accessible unisex W.C. are provided on the ground and roof levels, respectively.